# Sending Email to Users without a risk

Tags: javascript, firebase, email, google-cloud-functions

I need to send only special Users an Email. That is not a big amount. The Website must send 6  E-Mails a week. I found many solutions. I found this simple solution:  https://medium.com/@edigleyssonsilva/cloud-functions-for-firebase-sending-e-mail-1f2631d1022e
When you look at the code, I need to fill out the variables. So I must type in my Email and the Password. As the web is opensource I think that is a very bad way. Do you know other simple solutions or know how to do this without typing in password?

Comment: You can pass a password as an environment variable, check https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

Answer (score 2):

With this solution you are using firebase functions. You most certainly want to set some **environmental variables** to protect some sensitives data like your gmail password.

You can do this in firebase: go check their documentation right here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

The doc is going to help you set something like :

```
{
  "mailer": {
    "mail":"YOUR GMAIL ADRESS",
    "password":"YOUR GMAIL PASSWORD"
  }
}
```

So instead of you password in plain text you'll have this in your code :

```
'password': `${functions.config().mailer.password}`
```

Much safer right ?

Answer (score 0):

The web is not open source. If you run a script in the browser then yes, the user can read the code. The example you link, however, runs on the server in response to HTTP(S) requests, and as such is not readable by a visitor.