# How to send emails from Firebase without exposing password?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How to send emails from Firebase without exposing the password?

Following is the use of node mailer for sending firebase emails using cloud functions.

But here we will have to create a transporter with an email and password.
Is it possible to do it without a transporter (email and password) . i.e. anonymously. Cause storing password is not safe for this kind of applications.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
admin.initializeApp();

/**
* Here we're using Gmail to send 
*/
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'yourgmailaccount@gmail.com',
        pass: 'yourgmailaccpassword'
    }
});

exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {

        // getting dest email by query string
        const dest = req.query.dest;

        const mailOptions = {
            from: 'Your Account Name <yourgmailaccount@gmail.com>', // Something like: Jane Doe <janedoe@gmail.com>
            to: dest,
            subject: 'test', // email subject
            html: `<p style="font-size: 16px;">test it!!</p>
                <br />
            ` // email content in HTML
        };

        // returning result
        return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
            if(erro){
                return res.send(erro.toString());
            }
            return res.send('Sended');
        });
    });    
});
```

Comment: Kind of duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57933430/sending-email-to-users-without-a-risk

Answer (score 2):

You could set the credentials in function's [environment configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#set_environment_configuration_for_your_project).

To store the email and password, you can use the following command:

```
firebase functions:config:set nodemailer.email="username@domain.tld" nodemailer.password="your_password"
```

> After running `functions:config:set`, you must redeploy functions to make the new configuration available.

To use the config in your function, you use the `functions.config()` object:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: functions.config().nodemailer.email,
        pass: functions.config().nodemailer.password
    }
});
```